# Implementing js script for scrolling to a target in Clojurescrip - Re-frame

Tags: javascript, clojurescript, re-frame

I'm working on a Clojure project, using clojure, clojurescript, re-frame and reagent.
There is a button that I want when it is clicked, the user jumps to the related image tag by scrolling.
There are lots of buttons that each button should scroll the screen to the target picture.

As I'm new to clojure world, I don't know how to implement the js script into the project. I have created a button on the views.cljs file with dispatch to the events. But where should I implement the js part? As I've found, it must be in the events.cljs file, but if it's correct, I don't know how to implement that.

Please help me with this code. How should the js code looks like when it's going to be implemented in clojurescript?
Thank you in advance.

In views.cljs:

> [:button {:on-click #(rf/dispatch [::events/img-one])}]

Comment: What part is the part you are struggling with? Do you want to dispatch with rf? The actual JS to focus the image?

Comment: Thank you, @cfrick, I got the answer. Yeah, I thought I have to dispatch and put the code into the event.cljs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). I also don't think you have to modify `events.cljs`, just add this code into `views.cljs` (I also added some images for testing):

```
[:button {:on-click #(.scrollIntoView
                                   (.getElementById js/document "id3"))}
             "Click me"]

[:div
  [:div [:img#id1 {:src "" :style {:width 600 :height 1000 :background "red"}}]]
  [:div [:img#id2 {:src "" :style {:width 600 :height 1000 :background "pink"}}]]
  [:div [:img#id3 {:src "" :style {:width 600 :height 1000 :background "yellow"}}]]
```

With argument *behavior*, scrolling can be smooth:

```
[:button {:on-click #(.scrollIntoView
                                   (.getElementById js/document "id3")
                                   (js-obj "behavior" "smooth"))}
             "Click me"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Martin. That is what I was looking for. I thought it must be on the events.cljs file! But the behavior "smooth" does not working. It just jump to the picture.

Comment: @niloofar That can be caused by bad browser. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#browser_compatibility - Internet Explorer and Safari don't support options parameter.

Comment: Oh, the problem for behavior was typo! I wrote that with "u" in British way, behaviour. So it didn't work and just used to jump. Now it works, thanks a lot, Martin.